# Static method without a name

Tags: java, android, class, static

In an Android example class theres this method:

```
static {        
    addItem(...);
}
```

When I reference the class, the items are indeed added. I never saw a method like this, a. how is this called and b. I suppose this method is called whenever the class is referenced (or the first time it is referenced)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is Static initialization block and it will be loaded only when class is loading as Fouad said. If you want to perform the functionality inside the Static block when you want you can add a private static method instead. Have a look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html)

Answer (score 9):

This is called `static initializer` and the code inside it is invoked only once at class loading.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a method. It is a `static initializer`. It is a way of statically doing some work, on class load, like setting up some data.

Consider this:

```
static List<String> neverChangingNames;

static {
  neverChangingNames = new ArrayList<String>();
  neverChangingNames.add("Thomas");
  neverChangingNames.add("Derek");
  neverChangingNames.add("Michael");
  neverChangingNames = Collections.unmodifiableList(neverChangingNames);
}
```